# Symfony to Heroku composer install process failed with an error

Tags: symfony, heroku, composer-php

I try to put a site on Heroku but I have a problem when I make the command
`git push heroku master`

**WARNING: Your 'composer.lock' is out of date!
The 'composer.lock' file in your project is not up to date with the of incorrect packages or package versions.
The lock file is required in order to guarantee reliable and reproducible installation of dependencies across systems and deploys. It must always be kept in sync with 'composer.json'.
Whenever you change 'composer.json', ensure that you perform the following steps locally on your computer:

1. run 'composer update'
2. add all changes using 'git add composer.json composer.lock'
3. commit using 'git commit'
   Ensure that you updated the lock file correctly, and that you ran 'git add' on both files, before deploying again.
   Please remember to always keep your 'composer.lock' updated in lockstep with 'composer.json' to avoid common problems related to dependencies during collaboration and deployment.**

**ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts') in your 'composer.json'.
Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code, timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
check the details above, as they may be related to this error: - Your 'composer.lock' is out of date!****

```json
"scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "compile": [
            "php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate"
        ]
    }
```

If someone has an idea I'm interested

Comment: Did you read that error message? It contains all neccessary steps to resolve the problem. Also, this is not related to Symfony after all

Comment: I read the error message but I don't understand why the `post-install-cmd line` is a problem

Comment: What makes you think that this special line is to blame? Why not fix the root problem first?

Comment: I have fixed the problems in order but it still returns me the error on this line

Comment: Then please share more details, like the error message you are facing. If you commited an up-to-date `composer.lock`, the error message would not tell you that it is outdated